# Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a map that induces the zero map in the fundamental groups if $f$ nullhomotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a map that induces the zero map in the fundamental groups is $f$ nullhomotopic? It seems intuitively correct, however I cant come up with a proof or a counterexample
 Thanks in advance

Comment: This is false. In general, the way to make this claim is to lift the map to the universal cover of the space, but that only works if the universal cover is contractible. If you know that spheres have nontrivial higher homotopy groups, the claim is clearly false, because every map into $S^2$, for example, induces the trivial map on the fundamental group, but $\pi_3(S^2)\not\cong \{1\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true. For example, take the identity map of the 2 sphere.

The induced map on fundamental groups is zero because the fundamental group is zero. However it is not null homotopic because it induces the identity map on the second homology.